# Interval between next coming date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table structure as below, Now i want to calculate the interval between next coming date from second column

**TABLE STRUCTURE**

```
Calendar    |NEXT DAY    

15-07-1997   15-07-1997    
16-07-1997                  
17-07-1997                 
18-07-1997   18-07-1997     
19-07-1997                 
20-07-1997                 
21-07-1997                 
22-07-1997                 
23-07-1997                 
24-07-1997                 
25-07-1997                 
26-07-1997    26-07-1997
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
Calendar   |NEXT DAY    |DIFFDATE|

15-07-1997   15-07-1997    0
16-07-199                  2
17-07-1997                 1
18-07-1997   18-07-1997    0    
19-07-1997                 7
20-07-1997                 6
21-07-1997                 5
22-07-1997                 4
23-07-1997                 3
24-07-1997                 2
25-07-1997                 1
26-07-1997    26-07-1997   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead(ignore nulls)`:

```
select t.*,
       (coalesce(next_day,
                 lead(next_day ignore nulls) over (order by calendar)
                ) - calendar
       ) as diffdate
from t;
```